# Limiting number of requests in cassandra without causing starting timeout ticking

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

The DataStax Cassandra driver of version 4 has got a feature of the throttling.

The documentation [states](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.3/manual/core/configuration/reference/):

> Similarly, the request timeout encompasses throttling: the timeout starts ticking before the
> throttler has started processing the request; a request may time out while it is still in the
> throttler's queue, before the driver has even tried to send it to a node.

**Great**. However, let's say I have a dynamic list of some ids and I want to execute select requests to cassandra in parallel (using `executeAsync()`) for all ids in the list. Having list too large I will eventually face timeouts if requests are residing in the throttler's queue too long.

How can I overcome this issue? **Is there any built-in rate limiting technique** so I can do not care about how many requests in parallel I can execute, but just throw all of them to cassandra and then wait until they all are completed??

***UPD***: I am **not** interested in custom code solutions, as ofc we are capable to implement our own rate limit solution. I am asking precisely about **driver's** built-in mechanisms to achieve this.

Comment: version 4.x. 4.9 if you prefer.